# OOP Method chaining optional return

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, chaining

At this point, let's say I have a class like so:

```
class Sentence {
  __construct($content) {
    $this->content = $content;
  }
  public function grab_word($num) {
    $words = explode(" ", $this->content);
    return $words[$num+1];
  }
}
```

So the interface given would allow me to create a `new Sentence`, and then I could call the `grab_word()` class method to fetch a word in the sentence:

```
$sentence = new Sentence("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");
echo $sentence->grab_word(2);
```

However, what I'd like to do is add another chained class method, giving me the ability to capitalize this word.

```
$sentence->grab_word(2); # -> ipsum
$sentence->grab_word(2)->caps(); # -> IPSUM
```

Clearly, this won't work because chained methods require object inheritance. If I were to create `caps()` and chain that function - it would return an error due to the return not being the inherited `Sentence` object.

To sum it up, my question is how to I achieve the ability to chain these methods optionally, but still return a non-object whenever needed (like in my output example).

Comment: Short: you can't. Complex: You could craft an object to carry around the currently transformed value, then implement `__toString()` to have that object implicitly transformed into a string when needed. Certainly not worth the effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Broadly speaking, what you're asking is not possible.  Why don't you just always return the object you sometimes need to chain method calls onto?  Just return `new Word($words[ ... ])` and you'll be in a better position.

Now, when I say "broadly speaking", there are things you can do to make it possible to call different methods, that may live in different classes.  You can make use of `__call()` to implement something similar to ruby's mixins, though really quite inferior.  `__call()` will simply look at the method name that was invoked, then iterate a list of possible targets and see if they respond to that method, before delegating the invocation to that object (or raising an exception).

PS: This question hasn't got anything to do with inheritance.  Method chaining requires returning an object, not just implementing an inheritance hierarchy.  Of course, you may return `$this`, where that makes sense, but usually you return another object.

Comment: I wish I could chose all of the answers but you offered a comprehensive explanation first, so I'll accept yours. Thanks so much for the insight/tips! (I'm also up-voting all of the helpful answers)

Answer (score 4):

```
class Sentence {
  function __construct($content) {
    $this->content = $content;
  }
  public function grab_word($num) {
    $words = explode(" ", $this->content);
    return new Sentence($words[$num+1]);
  }
  public function caps() {
    return new Sentence(strtoupper($this->content));
  }
  function __toString(){
      return $this->content;
  }
}
```

an object with a __toString method isnt totally compatible with a string though. It's still an object, but, it will convert to string when explicitly used in a string context.

Comment: or creating a word class so both sentence and word.class.php both Inherit a well coded string class so intrinsic methods can be used on all string returns

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is fairly logical in some languages which treat String as an object. PHP is inspired by Perl and C and by design "string" is an not an object.

You can make it an object encapsulating it into a class:

```
class Word {
    private $content;
    function __construct($content){
        $this->content=$content;
    }
    function __toString(){
        return $this->content;
    }
    function caps(){
        strtoupper($this->content);
        return $this;
    }
}

class Sentence {
    function grab_word($num)
        $words = explode(" ", $this->content);
        return new Word($words[$num+1]);
    }
}
```

You should also look at answer by @chris as it offers you slightly different implementation. I would suggest that you don't create new object instances without explicit cloning, because it's a waste of resources and design of PHP focuses on quick and precise response from the server.